# Skeleton tracking using PointCloud2

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'd like to implement movement transfer from a human demonstrator to the robot. In order to do so, I firstly need skeleton tracking. Because I can't use a RGBD camera directly, I would either use rosbag recording of the relevant information to get point cloud data which should replace camera data or gazebo.

Apart from OpenPose, which doesn't seem to be fast enough, there doesn't seem to be any generic library which would allow to do skeleton tracking.  Nuitrack is proprietary and Nite seems to be discontinued.

How do you do skeleton tracking? Do you use SDK provided by the camera manufacturer directly and accept all the limitations or are there other more generic wrappers available?

P.S.: In the end, I will use Orbbec Astra Pro camera (using https://github.com/shinselrobots/astra_body_tracker), but their SDK expects that you connect camera directly or you get invalid licensing error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299746/skeleton-tracking-using-pointcloud2/) by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that if you build PCL with GPU and CUDA support, there is a tutorial how to detect people in point cloud data directly as well. See http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/gpu_people.php#gpu-people

---

Originally posted by [smihael](https://answers.ros.org/users/23102/smihael/) with karma: 45 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0